# What's the evolutionary benefit of stress and cortisol?

Tags: evolution

Stress and cortisol lower immunity and increase hard disease.

But why is it that way?

If that's true then we shouldn't be stressful at all.

What's the benefit of stress then?

Why do we (and most mamals) response to stress by lowering immunity? How do people that lower their immunity due to stress survive "better" in the gene pool?

Comment: Acute stress occurs. It is impossible to enter the world without it. Cortisol is part of the physiologic response. This question could be improved by researching the role of cortisol in response to acute stress and explaining what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a stress:  you have been bitten by a wolf, and it wants to bite you more.

Your body responds (among other things) with a surge of cortisol.

The cortisol

1:  Blunts immune response.  That inflamed hip you have needs to not slow you down.  That chronic cough needs to go away.  That stuff can wait.  You need to RUN.

2. Blood sugar goes up.  RUN!
3. Platelets go up.  You need to stop bleeding.
4. Repair / anabolic mechanisms are suppressed.  That stuff can wait too.
5. Testosterone levels plummet. Do not try to impress the ladies, you with your bleeding wound.  RUN!

The idea is that a stressor warranting a surge of cortisol is temporary.  Once you have found a safe cave the cortisol wanes and you can lick your wounds and build back your body.  Artificially elevated corticosteroid levels (from pills, or a steroid secreting cancer) are indeed tough on the body because of suppression of immunity and anabolic processes.

When people today talk about "stress" with jobs and grumpy roommates, it is not stress on the same level as a wolf attack.  Serious heavy duty stresses are what the glucocorticoid system evolved to handle.

Comment: The requirement for cortisol in response to acute stress remains important today. Illness, surgery, injury, and childbirth require high levels of cortisol.